# Disable hide modal window when click out of the modal jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a modal DIV:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="window_modal">
  .....
</div>
```

But when click out of the WINDOW, modal window close, and I want this windows close only using close button inside modal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the modal the data-attribute backdrop="static"

e.g.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="window_modal" data-backdrop="static">
  .....
</div>
```

All to find here:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#window_modal').on('hide', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

    });

 });</script>
```